# I can't figure out how to save the score on this dice game I've made. What should I change?

Tags: python, function

I am so close to finishing this simple game but I cant for the life of me figure out how to save the score with the def function. As every time it rolls it resets to 0 due to the score = 0 in the def. I tried to take it out , but it kept saying that it couldn't find the variable for score. I'm relatively new to coding, so please tell me a way to save the score, or to stop it from resetting.
Here is some of the code in Python (The problem is within #Roll)

#Roll#

```
import random

def roll(player):
score = 0
score2 = 0
if player == 1:
    print("Rolling for",P1,"...")
    dice1 = (random.randrange(1,7))
    dice2 = (random.randrange(1,7))
    dietotal = dice1 + dice2
    score = score + dietotal
    dice(dice1)
    dice(dice2)
    print("Your score so far is", score,)
else:
    print("Rolling for",P2,"...")
    dice1 = (random.randrange(1,7))
    dice2 = (random.randrange(1,7))
    dietotal = dice1 + dice2
    score2 = score2 + dietotal
    dice(dice1)
    dice(dice2)
    print("Your score so far is", score2,)
```

#Accounts#

```
password = 'wrong'
print("Welcome to the dice game!")
P1 = input("What is player 1's name?")
while password != 'right':
    password = input("What is the password?")
    if password == 'password':
        print("Ok", P1,"welcome!")
        password = 'right'
    else:
        print("Password is invalid, try again")

P2 = input("What is player 2's name?")
while password != 'wrong':
    password = input("What is the password?")
    if password == 'password':
        print("Ok", P2,"welcome!")
        password = 'wrong'
    else:
        print("Password is invalid, try again")
```

#Game#

```
rounds = 0
while rounds != 5:
    print("Its your turn to roll", P1,)
    start = input("Enter roll when you want to")
    while start != 'roll':
            print("This is invalid")
            start = input("Enter roll when you want to")
    else:
        roll(1)

    print("Its your turn to roll", P2,)
    start = input("Enter roll when you want to")
    while start != 'roll':
            print("This is invalid")
            start = input("Enter roll when you want to")
    else:
        roll(2)
        rounds = rounds + 1
```

Comment: how about not setting a score of 0 in function def? put it outside and define as global, or an alternative is to make a list (as to not use `global`) and then each time append 1 to it and at the end or whenever You need sum it

Comment: You specifically set the score to 0 every time you roll.  If that's not when you want to reset the score, then don't do that.  Move the reset to the proper point, according to your game rules.

Comment: If you want detailed help, please supply the expected [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) (MRE).
We should be able to copy and paste a contiguous block of your code, execute that file, and reproduce your problem along with tracing output for the problem points.  This lets us test our suggestions against your test data and desired output.
Show where the intermediate results differ from what you expected.
Don't expect us to enter test data, or to build a test file.
Instead, simply hard-code a test case that causes the problem.

Comment: Please don't include your question in the title. Keep the subject heading short.  Ask your question clearly in your text.

Comment: Questions about code behavior almost always have nothing to do with the editor or development environment used to write and submit the code to the Python (or other language) compiler/interpreter.

Comment: I'll be honest I don't know what I did, but I played with the global function and it now works, I changed it so it had a global function inside the define and it adds the total on each time now. Thanks to everyone who helped though!

Answer (score -1):

Try making your roll function return the result. In #Roll# put return score and return score2 where you have your print statements then remove the print statements.

In #Game# make the following changes:

Define vars score and score2

Change roll(1) -> score=score + roll(1)
print("Your score so far is", score,)

and

Change roll(2) -> score2=score2 + roll(2)
print("Your score so far is", score2,)

Comment: this answer has pretty poor quality, could You improve that?